# react-router-dom 4 routing questions

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use react-router-dom 4, But am unable to navigate directly to a route.

Here's a sample of my code:

```js
let Test = (props)  => (<div>This is a test component</div>);
let About = (props)  => (<div>About us</div>);

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="selected">About</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="selected">Test</NavLink>
          </nav>
          <Route exact path="/"  component={Test} />
          <Route exact path="/about"  component={About} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

When i try to just go to `localhost:3000/about`, i get **Not Found** in the browser.  But when i go to just `localhost:3000`, then click on the **About** link, i get redirected just fine.

in my Console, i get

> Uncaught Error: uBlock Origin: aborting content scripts for http://localhost:3000/about
>       at contentscript.js:90

Comment: You can see this work in a [real-world React App here](https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/budgeting-sample-app-webpack2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Webpack. If so, adding a few things to your webpack config should solve the issue. Specifically, `output.publicPath = '/'` and `devServer.historyApiFallback = true`. Here's an example webpack config below which uses both of ^ and fixes the refresh issue for me. If you're curious "why", [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually) will help.

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler!  That link is exactly what i was looking for to figure out what was going on.  My test server is just running _serve_, which doesn't seem to have a configuration file.  I'll just ditch _serve_ for  _webpack-dev-server_.

Answer (score 0):

when you go to localhost:3000/about,it's run server-side route,and the you don't set server-side route,so you got 404;when you go to just localhost:3000, then click on the About link,now, you run the client route that you have setted. In other word,it's run react-router-dom,so you can got the page